# Android device not shown unless restart adb

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

this is my first time asking question in Stack Overflow. I am facing a very annoying problem. I could not find my emulator in the device list in eclipse.

I had checked the `adb devices` and it could detect my device.

Everytime I need to use `killall adb` or `adb kill-server` + `adb start-server` to make my device re-appear in eclipse's device list. But after I had run my application once in my device, the device disappear again in the device list. I need to restart the adb everytime I run my application in my device.

Anyone got some clue about what's happening? Thanks. :)